# Show panel when record in table exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an Order model which is linked to two tables.

Sometimes the data is stored in either table but i want to know if i can use "if" statements in activeadmin to show if the record exists in the table or else hide the panel. Usually the data is in either one of the two tables.

The two tables that is linked to the Order model is here:

```
   panel 'Upgrade Order' do
     attributes_table_for order.order_upgrade do
       row :ictype
       row :idno
       row :number
       row :agree
     end

   end

    panel 'MNP Order' do
     attributes_table_for order.order_mnp do
       row :ictype
       row :idno
       row :number
       row :agree
     end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` statements in `ActiveAdmin`, something like this should work [`any?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/any%3F):

```
panel 'Upgrade Order' do
  attributes_table_for order.order_upgrade do
    row :ictype
    row :idno
    row :number
    row :agree
  end
end if Model.any?
```

or:

```
if Model.any?
  panel 'Upgrade Order' do
    attributes_table_for order.order_upgrade do
      row :ictype
      row :idno
      row :number
      row :agree
    end
  end
else
  render template: 'path_to_template'
end
```